# how to fix error [Developer Policy 1.2 - App is not loading or has broken functionality]

Tags: policy

We have now received the following error message from Facebook
"Platform Term 1.2
Developer Policy 1.2 - App is not loading or has broken functionality
Platform affected: Android
We found that the app did not load properly or had issues that prevented us from completing our review. Common examples of this include broken integrations and interface failures (such as broken buttons or links). This violates Developer Policy 1.2."
We have appealed in 5 times with video we were able to log in after correcting but still not accepted. Does anyone else have the same problem as me and how can I fix this problem? Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Hope it can be resolved

Comment: Same here. Anoying